# Syntax error near expression " vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
public class contacts
dim mydt as new datatable
Private Sub Contact_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With mydt
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Contacts", con)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(mydt)
        .AcceptChanges()
        .DefaultView.RowFilter = "([Unique id],Prefix,[First name],[Last name],Gender,Title,Company,Phone,Mobile,Fax,[b.email],[p.email],Reference,Address,[Address 2],Country,City,Zip,Facebook,GooglePlus,Instagram,Twitter,Website,Salary,Currency,[Group],[Id/Status],Note,[Added by]) LIKE '*'"
    End With
    userdatagrid.DataSource = mydt.DefaultView
```

i am getting "Syntax error near expression" in the line

```
.DefaultView.RowFilter = "([Unique id],Prefix,[First name],[Last name],Gender,Title,Company,Phone,Mobile,Fax,[b.email],[p.email],Reference,Address,[Address 2],Country,City,Zip,Facebook,GooglePlus,Instagram,Twitter,Website,Salary,Currency,[Group],[Id/Status],Note,[Added by]) LIKE '*'"
```

How should i fix this ?
or how do i populate a datatable from an sql database?

Comment: Your filter value doesn't make sense.  It has to be a valid `WHERE` clause, which that is not.  If you were to actually explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't actually do it, then maybe we could help you achieve it.  ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  By the way, that call to `AceptChanges` is pointless.  Also, ther's no point binding to the `DefaultView` because binding to the `DataTable` will display data from the `DefaultView` anyway.

Comment: "how do i populate a datatable from an sql database?"  You've already done that.  It's the filtering of that `DataTable` that you're failing at. What are you trying to achieve by setting that filter? If you don't want to filter the data at all then don't set any filter at all.

Comment: sir , i found this code in a MSDN forum...so...really didn't wonder it would have flaws!BY the way sir,i really don't understand the code anyway.Can u please explain what the .acceptchanges mean and why u said it was useless??

Comment: and u said my filter value doesn't make sense.U r right! But if i add WHERE clause, wouldn't i have to add a "=" to every column name ?e.g. Select * From Contacts WHERE [Unique ID]=@uid,gender=@gender.If i do that,what should i do next?What am i supposed to do with the "@"values.Can u please give me a fixed code or tell me what i'm missing ?

Comment: There aren't going to be any parameters, only literal values, and you don't include the word "WHERE" but yes, if you want to match every column then you have to actually compare every column.

Comment: If you don't understand the code then I suggest that you make an effort to do so.  Have you, form instance, read the documentation for the `RowFilter` property? Noone should ever be asking for help on using a specific type or member without having read the documentation for that type or member first.

Comment: sir i have multiple columns and as u said,having multiple columns require WHERE statement.So if i try this ""Select * from Contacts WHERE([Unique id],Prefix) values(@uid,@prefix) LIKE '*'"" then still doesn't make any sense either as i assign values to them but leave them unused.My goal is to filter a datagridview from a textbox.I found this exact code in a MSDN forum [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7402d01d-6a5e-4c3a-887f-61e1b1e6da80/filter-datasource-for-datagridview-control-with-textbox-string?forum=vbgeneral]..

Comment: If you're too lazy to learn how to write a WHERE clause then I'm not going to waste my time any further. No you did NOT find that exact code on that forum. You found an example that filtered on one column and matched every record. That post even provides URLs to relevant documentation to learn how to modify that to your needs but it was apparently too much trouble for you to read those pages.  I'm done.

Comment: A RowFilter where everything is Like * means there is no rowfilter, since it is Form Load do nothing to it.  Still cant see where youre initializing the connection object or even where it is declared.  `AcceptChanges` is not needed after a fill

Comment: should i remove LIKE from RowFilter ?

Comment: You **should** read [ask] and take the [tour] and **research** any and all new concepts presented in code you crib from elsewhere before you post here.  BTW the MSDN QA site is just hosted by MS - anyone who joins can answer just like here,  Sadly, perhaps, many of the docs have gone wiki too -